# Cannot type the € symbol in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I can type the euro symbol (`€`) in any other application with the standard keypress but not in PhpStorm. Nothing happens when I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known issue considered [not a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18339). <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is basically an alias for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. This last key combination is assigned by default to the `Edit` command provided by the *Perforce Integration* plug-in. You can verify it at:

**File → Settings → IDE Settings → Keymap**

Click on the magnifying class icon and press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>:

[image: Keymap]

Possible solutions:

- Disable the plugin if you don't need it:

  File → Settings → IDE Settings → Plugins
- Otherwise, change or disable the keybinding.

Whatever the reason, the *Browse History* binding does not interfere. In fact, it doesn't even work.

Answer (score 1):

I could not type # symbol and it was same issue as this one.

My story of solution:

1. Tried to write # symbol (Ctrl + Alt + X) and that typed nothing, just info in bottom left corner (something about finding Xpaths) showed up.
2. Then I went to Settings > Keymap and type 'xPath' in search field.
3. This way I found out that on that key shortcut was plugin about XPaths bound.
4. Go to plugins, find the plugin and disable it.
5. Restart IDE and then I can write # symbol as I need.