# PhpStorm: Auto Format adds Ø

Tags: format, phpstorm, autoformat

This is very hard to google, because when I search for the character Ø I get a lot of results but on the page itself when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the character Ø, all o's are marked as well...

Anyway, my problem: whenever I auto format in PhpStorm by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, the auto format works but also the character Ø is added to the file with the focus.

I had this problem on my laptop every now and then, but I seem to have it constantly on my private PC.

My keyboard is QWERTY - United States International. Region settings are Netherlands, language is English (United Kingdom). I believe this is the same on my laptop from work.

Is there a way to suppress the Ø character from being written when I use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to auto-format my files?

Comment: What is your OS? Linux of Windows? This is definitely an OS level thing. P.S. Have you though about changing shortcut for Reformat Code action?

Comment: What happens in a text editor when you use CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+L? Does it insert the Ø character outside of PhpStorm?

Comment: Windows. Yes, it inserts the character outside PHPStorm as well. The thing is that I have windows 10 on both systems, as far as I know all the settings are the same, the keyboard I use is the same, but one system has the problem very, very little (once in a thousand?), And is solved by rebooting PHPStorm, the other system has the problem always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's apparently a [known issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000600910-Shortcut-types-special-character) reported as [Shortcuts with CTRL + Left ALT offten launches bind shortcut and then inserts national letter](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186289) but there doesn't seem to be much movement around the ticket.

If you ask for [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710462/cannot-type-the-%E2%82%AC-symbol-in-phpstorm) opinion, I have the impression that the underlying Java libraries on which JetBrains products are built do not make a clear distinction between <kbd>AltGr</kbd>and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. In [US-International keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#US-International) <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> prints `Ø`.